# Spawn Asyncronous Python Process From Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a single page app that accepts a file and processes it in flask / python.  I'd like to know how to make my flask app spawn a separate, asymmetrical python process per uploaded file (within reason).  I know that Flask session would be required so that Flask could tell users apart but beyond that, I'm lost.  Advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Searching for Celery + Flask will also yield more results in this vein.  If you have further questions in more detail feel free to either edit the question to further clarify your particular question (and I'll happily vote to re-open) or ask another one!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588253/concurrent-asynchronous-processes-with-python-flask-and-celery